# Getting more then one value in the same time from Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 dictionaries the first one has a key that are match multiple duplicate values in the second one:

```
var firstDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
firstDic.Add("123", "Value1");
firstDic.Add("456", "Value2");
firstDic.Add("789", "Value3");
firstDic.Add("000", "Value4");

var secondDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
secondDic.Add("5d866ac0-abab-46c9-a951-e7b0cf25dc72", "123");
secondDic.Add("217ddba3-977f-45b8-a7f6-80c6fbcef16e", "123");
secondDic.Add("99867f65-22c1-4b6c-b1bb-3fa73af317a9", "456");
secondDic.Add("203f9cf7-98f8-40fc-a4ba-da3a62c7d795", "456");
secondDic.Add("9bdafb4c-4d5a-4c87-8b9d-d9b98473390a", "789");
secondDic.Add("d3a245f0-cc5b-4c08-aaff-475d64e27e8d", "000");
```

I have a foreach in which i`m iterating over every key in the first dictionary

```
foreach (var item in firstDic)
{
   //It`s only taking the first match in the secondDic
   var myKey = secondDic.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == item.Key);

}
```

Is it possible to extract all the keys from the second dictionary(secondDic)that has the values matching from the first dictionary key and store them in some data structure.

Tnx in advice!

Comment: Could you not just use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault`?

Comment: Explaining it like this will give you very literally exact answers. I'm not sure you need that. Dictionaries are powerful containers and foreaching over them is relatively slow. Could you explain your problem in more detail? For instance, how are you going to use the data after? Why are you using two Dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you don't need to use `FirstOrDefault()`, just use the `Where()` which will return a collection back :

```
 var myKeys = secondDic.Where(x => x.Value == item.Key);
```

and then you can iterate over it:

```
foreach(var item in myKeys)
{

}
```

or do whatever business logic needs to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
 var result = secondDic.Where(s => firstDic.Any(f => f.Key == s.Value))
                       .Select(s => s.Key)
                       .ToList();
```